# Clone doctrine entity with related one to many entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, clone

I created an entity called Landing with OneToMany relation to LandingContent. One Landing can have one or more contents.

I need clone this Landing entity and set in database with new id. (That's working fine). Also I need clone the LandingContent with new id too.

The clone method in Landing it's this:

```
 /**
     * Clones the Landing
     */
    public function __clone()
    {
        $this->id = null;
        $this->title = new LandingTitle('Copia de ' . $this->getTitle()->getValue());

        $contents = $this->getContents();
        $this->contents = new ArrayCollection();
        if(count($contents) > 0){
            foreach ($contents as $content) {
                $cloneContent = clone $content;
                $this->contents->add($cloneContent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Actually the code create a new record in Landing table with the new Landingitle and clone the contents but in the same Landing, not in the cloned Landing.

Any help will be appreciated.(I'm also trying to fix it searching in other questions here on SO).

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a setter to the contents to link them to the new Landing :

```
/**
 * Clones the Landing
 */
public function __clone()
{
    $this->id = null;
    $this->title = new LandingTitle('Copia de ' . $this->getTitle()->getValue());

    $contents = $this->getContents();
    $this->contents = new ArrayCollection();
    if(count($contents) > 0){
        foreach ($contents as $content) {
            $cloneContent = clone $content;
            $cloneContent->setLanding($this);
            $this->contents->add($cloneContent);
        }
    }
}
```